# C言語でのUTF-8文字列の正確な長さを取得する

Tags: c, unicode

UTF-8でのstrlen関数のようなものはありますか?
"こんにちは"という文字列の長さをstrlenで測ると5ではなく、15という数値が返ってきてしまいます。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *s = "こんにちは";
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(s)); // 15と表示される

    return 0;
}
```

どうすれば期待通りの5を得ることができるのでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117393/utf-8-strings-length-in-linux-c より、
`mbstowcs()` が使えるそうです。
ロケールは正しく設定する必要があるようですが。

その他にもリンク先には自分で実装する場合の例もありますので、参考にされてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: リンク先コメントで重要な指摘がされていますのでこちらでも: Unicode文字列の長さを扱う際には、合字の存在に気をつけて下さい。例えば「が」は日本語では1文字と数えられますが、Unicodeでの表現方法は「(そのまま)が」と「か＋゛(の合字)」の2種類が存在しています。Unicodeで私たちが普段目にする文字はコードポイントという構成要素に分解され、前者は1コードポイント、後者は2コードポイントを用いて表現します。単純な長さ計算ロジックではコードポイント数が求められ、期待する"文字数"ではないことに注意してください。なお。合字まで正しく考慮するには、膨大なテーブル定義が必要になります。

Answer (score 6):

苗字や地名の異体字や国旗、色違いの絵文字など、複数のコードポイントで構成される書記素クラスターを考慮する必要がある場合、ICU の BreakIterator を使います。書記素クラスターに対応していない文字列関数を使うと、知らないうちに書記素クラスターを壊してしまうおそれがあります。

Twitter のようにコードポイント単位で短い文字数制限をかける場合、ヒンドゥー語やチベット語など、結合文字を多用するアジア諸国の言語のユーザーにとって、使い勝手がわるくなる可能性があることも配慮する必要があります。

漢字の異体字をあらわすには基底字の次に異体字セレクターや Standardized Variant を続けます。葛飾区の「かつ」は <U+845B U+E0101> であらわすことができます。国旗は2文字の国コードを該当するコードポイントであらわします。日本の国コードである JP は <U+1F1EF U+1F1F5> になります。

BreakIterator のコードの例は次のようになります。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unicode/ubrk.h>

int len(const char *);

int main(void)
{
    const char* str = "葛\U000E0101飾区\U0001F1EF\U0001F1F5";
    printf("%s\n%d\n", str, len(str));

    return 0;
}

int len(const char *str)
{
    UText *ut;
    UBreakIterator *bi;
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    int len = 0;

    ut = utext_openUTF8(NULL, str, -1, &status);
    bi = ubrk_open(UBRK_CHARACTER, "ja_JP", NULL, 0, &status);
    ubrk_setUText(bi, ut, &status);

    while (ubrk_next(bi) != UBRK_DONE) {
        ++len;
    }

    utext_close(ut);
    ubrk_close(bi);

    return len;
}
```

書記素クラスターのサイズの上限はないので、バッファーオーバーフローに気をつける必要があります。
たとえば、「葛」の後ろに U+E0101 が1000個続いても1つの書記素クラスターとしてカウントされます。
もし書記素クラスターの上限値を設ける必要があれば、Unicode の [Stream-Safe Text Format](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Stream_Safe_Text_Format) をご参照ください。
基準値の例として128バイトもしくはコードポイント単位で32個前後という数値が挙げられています。

コードポイント単位で文字数を求めるには UText (utext.h) もしくは UnicodeString (ustring.h) の u_countChar32 を使います。次のコードは UText の例です。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unicode/utext.h>

int len(const char*);

int main(void)
{
    // U+20BB7 U+91CE U+5BB6
    const char* str = "野家"; 
    printf("%d\n", len(str));

    return 0;
}

int len(const char* str)
{
    UText *ut;
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    UChar32 c;
    int len = 0;

    ut = utext_openUTF8(NULL, str, -1, &status);

    for (c = utext_next32From(ut, 0); c > -1; c = utext_next32(ut)) {
        ++len;
    }

    return len;
}
```

自分で書記素クラスターの境界を判定するライブラリを実装する場合、それぞれのコードポイントから Unicode プロパティを判定するために [GraphemeBreakProperty.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/auxiliary/GraphemeBreakProperty.txt) に記載される対応表が必要になります。境界のルールは UAX#29 の [3.1.1 Grapheme Cluster Boundary Rules](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundary_Rules) をご参照ください。この節では、隣接する文字の Unicode プロパティの組み合わせが並べられており、国旗は GB8 (Regional_Indicator × Regional_Indicator)、基底字と異体字セレクターの組み合わせは GB9 ( × Extend)、通常の文字が隣接し合う場合は GB10 (Any ÷ Any) に該当します。テストケースのデータは [GraphemeBreakTest.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/auxiliary/GraphemeBreakTest.txt) をご参照ください。

Comment: 「Twitterのようにコードポイント単位で短い文字数制限をかける」の参考リンク："[Character Counting - Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters)" NFC正規化後に140コードポイントで制限という仕様とのことでした。

Comment: 調べていただきありがとうございます。Ruby 2.2 の String#unicode_normalize や JavaScript の String.prototype.normalize への対応も別の機会に検討する必要がありますね。

Answer (score 4):

[mrubyのソースコード](https://github.com/mruby/mruby/blob/master/mrbgems/mruby-string-utf8/src/string.c)を参考にした実装例です。

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char utf8len_codepage[256] =
{
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
  3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
};

int utf8len(const char* p)
{
    int len;
    int i;

    if (*p == 0) return 1;
    len = utf8len_codepage[(const unsigned char)*p];
    for (i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        if ((p[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) return 1;
    }
    return len;
}

int utf8strlen(const char* p)
{
    int len;
    for (len = 0; *p; ++len) {
        p += utf8len(p);
    }
    return len;
}

int main() {
    const char *s = "こんにちは";
    printf("%lu\n", utf8strlen(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: RFC 3629 が公開された2003年以降では (p[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80 の判定は脆弱なコードです。先行バイトが 0xE0、0xED、0xF0、0xF4 の場合、2番目のバイトの範囲が 0x80 と 0xBF の範囲よりも狭くなるからです。http://stackoverflow.com/a/13695364/531320

Answer (score 3):

（今日びのことなので、 Unicode を使用する環境だけを対象とします。）

Unicode では、日本語の文字もそれぞれ Unicode 文字として扱われます。各文字で、「最初の２ビットが `11` で始まり、最初の 2ビットが `10` であるバイトが続く限りそれは 文字の一部である」というルールがあり、１文字は可変長となります。各バイトの上位2ビットを見ながら数えていかなければなりません。

Unicode を数えるときは、以下の `strlen_utf8()` のような形になります。

※  strlen_utf8() は、”[UTF-8 & Unicode, what's with 0xC0 and 0x80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911536/utf-8-unicode-whats-with-0xc0-and-0x80/3911566#3911566)" から持ってきています。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long strlen_utf8(char *s)
{
  long i = 0, j = 0;
  while (s[i])
  {
    if ((s[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) j++;
    i++; }
  return j;
}

int main() {
    char *s = "こんにちは";

    printf("string  : %s\n", s);

    size_t i = 0;
    printf("bytes~16: ");
    while (i < 16) printf("%02X ",((const unsigned char *)s)[i++] & 0xff);
    printf("\n");

    printf("strlen  : %lu\n", strlen(s)); // 15
    printf("strlen_utf8: %lu\n", strlen_utf8(s)); // 5

    return 0;
}
```

出力:

```
string  : こんにちは
bytes~16: E3 81 93 E3 82 93 E3 81 AB E3 81 A1 E3 81 AF 00
strlen  : 15
strlen_utf8: 5
```

今回、文字列は、

```
E3 81 93 E3 82 93 E3 81 AB E3 81 A1 E3 81 AF 00
```

> **こ** <kbd>e3</kbd> <kbd>81</kbd> <kbd>93</kbd>  
>   **ん** <kbd>e3</kbd> <kbd>82</kbd> <kbd>93</kbd>  
>   **に** <kbd>e3</kbd> <kbd>81</kbd> <kbd>ab</kbd>  
>   **ち** <kbd>e3</kbd> <kbd>81</kbd> <kbd>a1</kbd>  
>   **は** <kbd>e3</kbd> <kbd>81</kbd> <kbd>af</kbd>  
>   0x0   <kbd>00</kbd>

というデータとなっていました。これに対して、`strlen` 関数は、 「0x0 が発見されるまで1バイトづつ数えていく」動作で、Unicode の５文字を、15とカウントしました。

Comment: +1; せっかくの詳細解説ですから、文字集合としてのUnicodeと、その文字符号化方式としてのUTF-8を明確にされた方が良いかと思います。

Comment: RFC 3629 が公開された2003年以降では s[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80　の判定は不正なバイト列を見逃してしまう脆弱なコードです。先行バイトが 0xE0、0xED、0xF0、0xF4 の場合、2番目のバイトの範囲が 0x80 から 0xBF の範囲よりも狭くなるからです。

Comment: コメント確認しました。時間が取れたときに見直して、書き直したく思っています。（不正なバイト列は完全な漏れです、これも見直してみます。）

Answer (score 2):

Unicode 文字列を扱うための `wchar_t`(wide char)という型が用意されています。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
  wchar_t *s = L"こんにちは";
  printf("%d\n", wcslen(s));
  return 0;
}
```

Wide char string の長さを得る関数は `wcslen()` です。また、文字列には `L`(Long) プレフィックスを付けて wide char であることを示す必要があります。

まぁ、あまり使いやすいとは言えませんので、他のライブラリを使われた方が良いと思います。

Comment: 厳密には`wchar_t`＝Unicodeとは限りません。環境によっては`wchar_t`がUnicodeとなることが有ります。ただしこの場合でも`wchar_t`がUTF-8である可能性はまずなく、大抵はUTF-16かUTF-32となっています。

Comment: WCHAR_MAX と 0xFFFF を比較すれば、16ビットであるか判定できます。16ビットの場合、上位サロゲート (0xD800 から 0xDBFF) と下位サロゲート (0xDC00 から 0xDFFF) の組の数を wcslen から引く必要があります。

Answer (score 0):

以下の様にします。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    wchar_t *s = L"こんにちは";
    printf("%lu\n", wcslen(s));//%lu の代わりに %zuを使用する方が良いです

    return 0;
}
```

---

Visual studio を使用している場合、シフトコードそのまま（マルチバイト文字列）で以下の様にできます。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *s = "こんにちは";
    printf("%lu\n", _mbslen(s));

    return 0;
}
```